# Send a Python 3.x API POST request without killing webserver

Tags: python-3.x

So I sent a request to a website using an API key and the site (REDCAP) became unresponsive for nearly 10 minutes. The request I made ultimately completed successfully, but I'm unsure of how to prevent this from happening again. Should I have made a bunch of smaller request instead of one large one?

The key and value pairs themselves take up about as many characters are exampled below, but there are many groups of them, about 600 or so being sent in one post request.
[{'KEY1': 'VALUE1', 'KEY2': 'VALUE2', 'KEY3':'VALUE3'},...{x600}]

The knowledge I have about python has been cobbled together over the course of a couple weeks so I not even sure what I need to ask exactly to prevent this from happening again. After a bit of digging I saw that I should have also included a timeout duration in the post request and should add code to handle that when it fails, but that does not help me with my biggest problem, which is not bringing the site to a grinding halt.

I'll provide my code for context, and I'm sure there are 100 things that could be done better or differently, but it worked as intended more or less so I'm not asking for feedback on my code, though will take any advice given. I've obfuscated anything I wasn't comfortable sharing on the web with three hash marks ###.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests,json,logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='###.log', \
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', \
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', \
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

#TOKEN = '###' #Live
TOKEN = '###' #Test
URL = '###'

dload = {
    'token': TOKEN,
    'content': 'record',
    'format': 'json',
    'type': 'flat',
    'fields[0]': '###',
    'rawOrLabel': 'raw',
    'rawOrLabelHeaders': 'raw',
    'exportCheckboxLabel': 'false',
    'exportSurveyFields': 'false',
    'exportDataAccessGroups': 'false',
    'returnFormat': 'json',
    'filterLogic': 'datediff([###],"TODAY","d",true) < 7'
}

dloadget=requests.post(URL,dload)
dmeta=dloadget.json()
logging.debug('Raw exported data: %s \n',dmeta)

if len(dmeta) == 0:
    logging.info('Records up to date')
else:
    for i,tpoints in enumerate(dmeta):
        dmeta[i].update({'###':None})

    logging.debug('Raw imported data: %s \n',dmeta)

    DATA = json.dumps(dmeta)
    fields = {
        'token': TOKEN,
        'content': 'record',
        'format': 'json',
        'type': 'flat',
        'overwriteBehavior': 'overwrite',
        'data': DATA
    }

    r2=requests.post(URL, data=fields)

    if r2.status_code == 200:
        logging.info('global notes log updated')
    else:
        logging.warning('updated failed %s',r2)
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in your code, but in the api that processes your request.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do about it then?

Comment: If you cannot check the code of the api the only thing you can do is reglement the amount of data the api has to process.

Comment: Long calls were causing problems with our REDCap server too.  So we added batching to [`REDCapR::redcap_read()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_read.html).  [PyCap](https://github.com/redcap-tools/PyCap) might have batching, and maybe some of these [other libraries](http://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/) have batching that you could use.